# BCS theory without breaking symmetry?

Tags: superconductivity, higgs, symmetry-breaking

I'm studying the analogies between the Higgs mechanism and superconductivity, specially, the BCS theory.

To develop the BCS theory, a mean field aproximation is done, which breaks the gauge invariance. Is symmetry breaking happening in nature? An exact treatment conserves the symmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1. The theory can be made gauge-invariant, still BCS gives almost all the correct predictions without it.
2. You can define a gauge-invariant but non-local order parameter. Knowing this exists, you can safely use the non-invariant one for most purposes.
3. Symmetry may perhaps not be broken in the strictest sense, but the best physical insight is still obtained by symmetry breaking and generalized rigidity. (This point is unrelated to lack of gauge invariance.)

**Recovering gauge invariance**

One of the main points of contention after BCS published their 1957 paper was the lack of gauge invariance. This is just because they leave out the coupling to the electromagnetic field, unless they need it to describe electromagnetic consequences such as the Meissner effect.

This was resolved however very quickly by Anderson in 1958 and 1962/3, and also by Nambu.

Anderson recounts some interesting things about this history in the talk "It's not over until the Fat Lady sings", which is reprinted in his book "More and Different." A particularly interesting one is:

> When I saw Landau in December 1958, he remarked that Gor'kov has derived the Ginzburg-Landau theory from BCS expressed in Green's function language and that since Ginzburg-Landau theory is gauge invariant, there is no problem.

Although he follows up that this is in fact not a solution [to the problem in BCS theory].

Anderson's insight was that you need to worry about the dynamics of collective modes, namely the longitudinal electronic mode, the plasma mode. This couples to the longitudinal part of the now-massive gauge field, and the total is gauge invariant. This is now called the Anderson-Higgs mechanism.

Still, you can see this most easily in Ginzburg-Landau theory.

**Symmetry breaking**

To get a good physical picture of the nature of superfluids and superconductors, it's very useful to understand the symmetry breaking description. This is the origin of the *generalized rigidity* (another term due to Anderson), which gives stability to the superconducting state, leads to the collective modes (would-be Nambu-Goldstone mode) and the Josephson effect. There are however two problems with this picture:

1. Due to the coupling to the electromagnetic field, it is not possible to define an order parameter that is both gauge-invariant and local. There are three ways to deal with this:

   1. Ignore this problem and just use the complex scalar field as order parameter. This is what BCS did, and as you can see from the textbook treatment, it doesn't lead to any problems other than the lack of gauge invariance (i.e. it gives correct predictions for physical observables).
   2. Use a certain gauge-fix. This is essentially a more general version of the above.
   3. Define a gauge-invariant but non-local order parameter. This was done by Dirac, and discussed pretty well in the beginning of [Hansson et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327). Knowing that a gauge-invariant order parameter exists, it's basically safe to take the other two options.
2. [Leggett argues](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01883640) that no symmetry is broken at all in superfluids. In atomic superfluids this is easy to see: phase and number are conjugate variables, and in an atomic condensate, you know the number of particles exactly, meaning the phase is undefined. He says you can get everything from just using the macroscopic occupation of the ground state. In superconductors this may be less of an argument, since you don't know exactly how many electrons form Cooper pairs. Note this has nothing to do with gauge invariance at all: it's the same for neutral superfluids.

   But this is all a bit besides the point: a lot of physical insight is gained from understanding broken symmetry, putting superfluids and superconductors on equal footing to magnets, crystalline solids and all other ordered states. [This seems to be the opinion of basically everybody but Leggett]

Comment: Concerning the last sentence: some people are of the same opinion as Legget for Bogoliubov theory, arguing you should use an approximation than strictly conserve the number of particles. But from what I understand, this gives exactly the same results than standard Bogoliubov theory, but in a more complicated fashion...

Comment: @Adam, could you give some resource reccomendations of the discussions you mention? I find it fascinating that these two approaches give the same result.

Comment: @LucasBaldo a good place to start for these number-conserving approaches would be 10.1103/PhysRevA.57.3008